# Leaflet markers won't update after checkbox filtering

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I've managed to return the data according to the ticked checkbox. I see the items in my console.log changing.

The only problem is that the markers on the map aren't changing. I think because I don't trigger a reload but I use a change eventlistener on the checkbox. Anybody that can help me out?

My code:

The file:

```
import { maps, customOptions } from "../leaflet.js";

let entries = [];
let filteredEntries = [];

async function bootThis() {
    const endpoint = 'ENDPOINT';

    const boot = 
    `
    fragment BootQuery on test_test_Entry {
        id
        crops
        country
        year
        testType
        lon
        lat
        specsTrial
        entryStatus
    }
    query {
        boot: entries(section: "test") {
            title
            ...BootQuery
        }
    }
    `

    fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'
           },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: boot })
        })
            document.querySelector( '#resultsNumber > p').innerHTML = `${data.data['boot'].length}`

            // This takes all the checkboxes from the countries filter tab
            const countriesCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name="countries"]');

            // We set our data to a variable
            entries = data.data['boot']
            const countriesCheckboxesArray = Array.from(countriesCheckboxes);
            filteredEntries = entries

            // For each checkbox, we add a change eventlistener
            // We filter on all our data to get the items that correspons with the value from the checkbox
            countriesCheckboxesArray.forEach(checkbox => {
                checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
                    const values = countriesCheckboxesArray
                    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
                    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value)
                    filteredEntries = entries.filter(feature => values.includes(feature.country));
                    console.log(filteredEntries);
                });
            });

            // We loop through our data to add the markers.
            // FilteredEntries gets updated but it doesn't trigger a rerender
            filteredEntries.forEach((feature) => {
                const keys = Object.keys(feature);
                L.marker([feature.lat, feature.lon]).addTo(maps).bindPopup(
                    `
                    <strong>${feature.title}</strong>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <p><strong>${findKey(keys, 'crops')}: </strong>${feature.crops}</p>
                    <p><strong>${findKey(keys, 'country')}: </strong>${feature.country}</p>
                    <p><strong>${findKey(keys, 'testType')}: </strong>${feature.testType}</p>
                    <p><strong>${findKey(keys, 'year')}: </strong>${feature.year}</p>
                    <p><strong>${findKey(keys, 'entryStatus')}: </strong>${feature.entryStatus}</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p><strong>${findKey(keys, 'specsTrial')}: </strong>${feature.specsTrial}</p>
                    `, customOptions);
                
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
};

function convertCountry(country) {
    if(country === 'BE') {
        return 'Belgium'
    }
    else if(country === 'NL') {
        return 'The Netherlands'
    }
    else if(country === 'FR') {
        return 'France'
    }
    else if(country === 'IT') {
        return 'Italy'
    }
    else {
        return 'Hungary'
    };
};

function findKey(array, key) {
    const look = array.find(feature => feature === key)
    return look.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + look.slice(1).replace(/[A-Z]/g, 
    function(match) {
        return match === match.toUpperCase() ? ' ' + match.toLowerCase() : match;
    });
};

await bootThis();
```

[image: Before and after checking a box]

Comment: You don't do anything with`filteredEntries` after filtering

Comment: So at this moment, my brain is all foggy.. so what should I do?
Return filteredEntries?